# How to define {min,max} matches in treetop peg

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, treetop

With Ruby's regular expressions I could write /[0-9]{3,}/ I can't figure out how to write this in treetop other than:

```
rule at_least_three_digit_number
  [0-9] [0-9] [0-9]+
end
```

Is there a 'match [at least|most] n' rule for treetop?

Comment: (closed and re-opened to clear the flags, as the duplicate has been deleted by OP)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like PEGs don't have some of the RE convenience operators, but in return you do get a much more powerful expression matcher.

Comment: I belive this is a implementation issue, one could definitely write `a{2,3}` instead of `aa / aaa` if the implementations allows it (treetop does not afaik).

Comment: Nope, it _is_ possible with treetop. See Luke's answer.

Answer (score 1):

http://treetop.rubyforge.org/syntactic_recognition.html

> A generalised repetition count (minimum, maximum) is also available.
>
> 'foo' 2.. matches 'foo' two or more times
>
> 'foo' 3..5 matches 'foo' from three to five times
>
> 'foo' ..4 matches 'foo' from zero to four times